# Atom editor now opens directories

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate

my Ubuntu mate started open dirs with Atom editor. Previously my file manager was Caja, but something happend and now when I click `Places -> Home`, it starts Atom. Also PhpStorm's context menu item "Open in File Manager" was changed to "Open in Atom". How can I unset Atom as file manager and set it back to Caja?

Tried:

`sudo apt --reinstall install caja` - no effect

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure caja` - no effect

Comment: i don't use mate, but there should be option to select default applications in settings.

Comment: @TahsinRahman Contol Center -> Preferred applications is what I looked for. Convert your comment to answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Contol Center -> Preferred applications` and change default file manager from there.